# a-frame animation - coloring text (or other primitives) from side to side

Tags: aframe

Currently, as I see it, with the simple animation tag, the whole text change the color. 
I want to break it so at the beginning the left (or right) letter will be colored, then the second, and so on.

Alternatively, I want to color a primitive, such as a cube, from side to side.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, in theory is everything possible. What you've tried?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but you'd probably have to write your own shader to accomplish this.

Comment: I didnt try something too special. For example, the following code gives me a plane with a text on it, and when the user look into the plane the color of the text changing from green to white (slowly..).  I want the text to be colored from side to side. 
  
  
<a-entity position="0 -1 -5"
  geometry="primitive: plane; height: auto; width: auto"
  material="color: blue"
  text="width: 5; color:white; value: Text to be colored.">
      <a-animation begin="fusing" attribute="text.color" from="white" to="green" dur="2000" fill="forward"></a-animation>
    </a-entity>
  </a-scene>